# ZF2 DI extended interface error Invalid instantiator of type "NULL"

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get a `Zend\EventManager\EventManager` from a Di

```
$di     = new Di();
$di->configure(new Config(array(/*etc*/));
$events = $di->get('Zend\EventManager\EventManager');
```

However I get this error

**Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Zend\Di\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManagerInterface".'

I believe it is because EventManagerInterface extends SharedEventManagerInterface?

I have tried

```
'preferences'   => array(
    'Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManagerInterface' 
        => 'Zend\EventManager\EventManager',
),
```

and also defining an instantiator

```
'Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManagerInterface' => array(
    'instantiator' => 'Zend\EventManager\EventManager::__construct'
),
```

What should be the config to over come this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Zend\EventManager\EventManager` is not a valid `Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManagerInterface`: use a `Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManager` instead.

Use following configuration if you want to inject a shared event manager:

```php
'di' => array( 
    'instance' => array(
        'preference' => array(
            'Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManagerInterface' 
                => 'Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManager',
        ),
    ),
),
```

That will basically tell `Zend\Di` to use a `Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManager` each time a generic `Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManagerInterface` is requested.

I have a working example in [this blogpost](http://ocramius.github.com/blog/zend-framework-2-controllers-and-dependency-injection-with-zend-di/).

Comment: It didn't quite work out of the box, we're there any other assumed config values?

Comment: Weird. Just tried it myself (see https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/5099518 ) and it failed because it tries to inject something because of the EventManagerInterface... Works on ZF2 `2.0.*` though.

Comment: Not to worry, ended up using the Service Manager instead.